# on delete cascade by default set to on delete restrict in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (`music,music_details`).The description of the tables has mentioned bellow

music:

```
music | CREATE TABLE `music` (
`music_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`movie_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`movie_image` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`music_director` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`cast` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`music_id`)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

music_details:

```
music_details | CREATE TABLE `music_details` (
`music_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`songtitle` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`duration` time DEFAULT NULL,
`artist` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`lyricist` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `music_id` (`music_id`),
CONSTRAINT `music_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`music_id`) REFERENCES `music` (`music_id`) on delete cascade on update cascade
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

now my problem is `'on delete cascade'` is working fine only at that instance,after some time it set to default(`on delete restrict`).what is the problem.

Comment: yes in my table the FK action by default changing to restrict even though i specify 'on delete cascade'

Comment: because if i delete any record from parent table,automatically the database delete the corresponding record from child table.

Comment: after one day it is changing to 'on delete restrict'.

Comment: delete from music where music_id=266;
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`movie
site`.`music_details`, CONSTRAINT `music_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`music_id`) REFERENCES `mu
sic` (`music_id`))

Comment: i run the above query the above error is coming.

Comment: And if you now run `SHOW CREATE TABLE music_details`?

Comment: music_details | CREATE TABLE `music_details` (
`music_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`songtitle` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`duration` time DEFAULT NULL,
`artist` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`lyricist` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `music_id` (`music_id`),
CONSTRAINT `music_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`music_id`) REFERENCES `music` (`music_id`)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

Comment: if i run the 'show create table music_details' my table structure is like above.

Comment: One thing that is slightly curious is that the code blocks in your question appear also to be pasted from `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, but the foreign key actions are in lowercase?  I'm very surprised that MySQL didn't format them in uppercase.  How did you create the foreign key constraint?

Comment: actually foreign key constraint is in upper case.My above code is copied from notepad.i think that is not a problem.

Comment: It just concerns me that you are editing the output in Notepad prior to pasting here... perhaps something important is getting changed along the way?

Comment: how to resolve my problem.If i restart my database(i turn of my computer)foreign key constraint is set to default constraint.